# jsoup - find element and remove it together with the previous element

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm trying to extract some data from a table of a stock market historical prices in Android. The table sometimes include a row that I'd need to remove, so to have a clean table. In the snippet below the row is in the third tr. I found a way to remove the cell with the dividend using

```
html = document.select("td[class=\"yfnc_tabledata1\"][align=\"center\"]");
            html.remove();
```

But I'm not sure on how to also remove the td with the date (May 4, 2015). Any ideas? I'm then getting the elements by class "yfnc_tabledata1" and going through them to find the data I need.

```html
<tr>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap align="right">May 5, 2015</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.69</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.96</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">27.64</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">27.71</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">4,595,800</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">27.58</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap align="right">May 4, 2015</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.67</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.80</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.35</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.61</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">33,537,800</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.47</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap align="right">May 4, 2015</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="center" colspan="6">0.26 Dividend</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap align="right">May 1, 2015</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.68</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.68</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.68</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.68</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">0</td>
  <td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">28.28</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it myself, but you could try to do something like this:

```
document.select("td[class=\"yfnc_tabledata1\"][align=\"center\"]").parents();
```

This way you would get the enclosing "tr" and you could remove the entire row.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution already.

```
for( Element element : document.select("td[class=\"yfnc_tabledata1\"][align=\"center\"]")) {
                el = element.parent();
                el.remove();
            }
```

In this way I find the td with the dividend, I get its parent and remove it all. Seems to work.